# Why does sklearn's PCA not return reproducible results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using [scikit's PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and have noticed some really strange behavior. Essentially, when using more than 500 samples, the result is not reproducible. This example shows what's happening:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

Ncomp = 15
Nsamp = 501
Nfeat = 30

PCAnalyzer = PCA(n_components = Ncomp)
ManySamples = np.random.rand(Nsamp, Nfeat)
TestSample = np.ones((1, Nfeat))

print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
```

It outputs:

```
>>> print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
[[-0.25641111  0.42327221  0.4616427  -0.72047479 -0.12386481  0.10608497
   0.28739712 -0.26003239  1.27305465  1.05307604 -0.53915119 -0.07127874
   0.25312454 -0.12052255 -0.06738885]]
>>> print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
[[-0.26656397  0.42293446  0.45487161 -0.7339531  -0.16134778  0.15389179
   0.27052166 -0.33565591  1.26289845  0.96118269  0.5362569  -0.54688338
   0.08329318 -0.08423136 -0.00253318]]
>>> print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
[[-0.21899525  0.38527988  0.45101669 -0.73443888 -0.20501978  0.09640448
   0.17826649 -0.37653009  1.04856884  1.10948052  0.60700417 -0.39864793
   0.18020651  0.08061955  0.05383696]]
>>> print(PCAnalyzer.fit(ManySamples).transform(TestSample))
[[-0.27070256  0.41532602  0.45936926 -0.73820121 -0.18160026 -0.13139435
   0.28015907 -0.28144421  1.16554587  1.00472104  0.16983399 -0.67157762
  -0.3005816   0.54645421  0.09807374]]
```

Reducing the number of samples (`Nsamp`) to 500 or less, or increasing the number of components (`Ncomp`) to 20 or more, fixes the issue - but this is not practical for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the default solver used by `sklearn`. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

> the solver is selected by a default policy based on X.shape and n_components: if the input data is larger than 500x500 and the number of components to extract is lower than 80% of the smallest dimension of the data, then the more efficient ‘randomized’ method is enabled. Otherwise the exact full SVD is computed and optionally truncated afterwards.

If you need reproducible results, use a different solver, or set the `random_state`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, reading the documentation helps:

> It uses the LAPACK implementation of the full SVD or a randomized truncated SVD by the method of Halko et al. 2009, depending on the shape of the input data and the number of components to extract.

This solves the issue:

```
PCAnalyzer = PCA(n_components = Ncomp, svd_solver = 'full')
```